# How to use ESLint with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, eslint

I'm attempting to use the ESLint linter with the Jest testing framework.

Jest tests run with some globals like `jest`, which I'll need to tell the linter about; but the tricky thing is the directory structure, with Jest the tests are embedded with the source code in `__tests__` folders, so the directory structure looks something like:

```
src
    foo
        foo.js
        __tests__
            fooTest.js
    bar
        bar.js
        __tests__
            barTest.js
```

Normally, I'd have all my tests under a single dir, and I could just add an `.eslintrc` file there to add the globals... but I certainly don't want to add a `.eslintrc` file to every single `__test__` dir.

For now, I've just added the test globals to the global `.eslintrc` file, but since that means I could now reference `jest` in non-testing code, that doesn't seem like the "right" solution.

Is there a way to get eslint to apply rules based on some pattern based on the directory name, or something like that?

Comment: This is a bit too brute force for an actual answer, but you could have a separate linting task that manually uses an`eslint-test` file with a glob, e.g. `eslint **/__tests__/*.js -c eslint-test.yml`. That said, I don't think there's much danger of a `jest` or `beforeEach` global leaking out into production code ;)

Answer (score 885, accepted):

[The docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest) show you are now able to add:

```
"env": {
    "jest/globals": true
}
```

To your `.eslintrc` which will add all the jest related things to your environment, eliminating the linter errors/warnings.

You may need to include `plugins: ["jest"]` to your esconfig, and add the `eslint-plugin-jest` plugin if it still isn't working.

Comment: With this method the usage of "describe" or "it" outside of files that match the "*.test.js" or "__tests__/*.js" pattern will not result in linting errors. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: @l0rin you could add a `.eslintrc` file that extend you default `.eslintrc` in your `__tests__` folder. If you have same problem as OP (multiple test folders), then you can generate those `.eslintrc` with a template and a tiny bash script (something like`ls **/__tests/ | xargs cp templates/.eslintrc`)

Comment: related link [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)

Comment: Is this still accurate? The docs specifically say `"jest/globals": true` rather than `"jest": true`.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes good spot. I have updated the answer accordingly :)

Comment: To be clear, you have to include `plugins": ["jest"]` to your  esconfig, and add  the eslint-plugin-jest plugin.

Answer (score 96):

ESLint supports this as of version >= 4:

```
/*
.eslintrc.js
*/
const ERROR = 2;
const WARN = 1;

module.exports = {
  extends: "eslint:recommended",
  env: {
    es6: true
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        "**/*.test.js"
      ],
      env: {
        jest: true // now **/*.test.js files' env has both es6 *and* jest
      },
      // Can't extend in overrides: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8813
      // "extends": ["plugin:jest/recommended"]
      plugins: ["jest"],
      rules: {
        "jest/no-disabled-tests": "warn",
        "jest/no-focused-tests": "error",
        "jest/no-identical-title": "error",
        "jest/prefer-to-have-length": "warn",
        "jest/valid-expect": "error"
      }
    }
  ],
};
```

Here is a workaround (from another answer on here, vote it up!) for the "extend in overrides" limitation of eslint config :

```
overrides: [
  Object.assign(
    {
      files: [ '**/*.test.js' ],
      env: { jest: true },
      plugins: [ 'jest' ],
    },
    require('eslint-plugin-jest').configs.recommended
  )
]
```

From https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8813#issuecomment-320448724

Comment: Thank you, this is totally the right solution for this question, as it actually answers it. worked for me!

Comment: This is great!  With updating my ESLint to version >= 4 and adding a `"files"` and `"env"` object to `"overrides"` in `eslint.rc` I no longer have to worry about Jest specific syntax passing linting outside of the testing files.

Comment: Excellent solution and also works for other frameworks (jasmine) when you have a non-standard folder structure.

Comment: I'm the guy who wrote the accepted answer - this answer is much better than mine! Although at the time I wrote my answer, it was the only way to solve this problem well.

Comment: ESLint now supports extending in overrides

Answer (score 33):

You can also set the test env in your test file as follows:

```
/* eslint-env jest */

describe(() => {
  /* ... */
})
```

Comment: this worked. thanks!

Answer (score 20):

To complete Zachary's answer, here is a workaround for the "extend in overrides" limitation of eslint config :

```
overrides: [
  Object.assign(
    {
      files: [ '**/*.test.js' ],
      env: { jest: true },
      plugins: [ 'jest' ],
    },
    require('eslint-plugin-jest').configs.recommended
  )
]
```

From https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/8813#issuecomment-320448724

Answer (score 14):

As of 2021, I think the correct way or at least the one that works is to install `@types/jest` and `eslint-plugin-jest`:

```
npm i -D eslint-plugin-jest @types/jest
```

And adding the Jest plugin into `.eslintrc.js` with the overrides instruction mentioned by @Loren:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: ["jest"],
  ...
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.test.js"],
      env: { "jest/globals": true },
      plugins: ["jest"],
      extends: ["plugin:jest/recommended"],
    },
  ],
  ...
};
```

This way you get linting errors in your source files as well as in test files, but in test files you don't get linting errors for `test` and other Jest's functions, but you will get them in your source files as they will appear as undefined there.

Comment: Many solutions purposed to put `"jest/globals": true` but it seems to make Eslint to stop working properly in other js files. But this solution is working flawlessly for me. It allows eslint to lint `.test` and `.js` files properly.

Comment: you can update a file rule to `"**/*.test.[j|t]s"`

Answer (score 12):

I solved the problem [REF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest)

Run

```sh
# For Yarn
yarn add eslint-plugin-jest -D

# For NPM
npm i eslint-plugin-jest -D
```

And then add in your `.eslintrc` file

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb","plugin:jest/recommended"],
}
```

Answer (score 5):

First install **eslint-plugin-jest**

Running:

```bash
yarn add eslint-plugin-jest
```

or

```bash
npm install eslint-plugin-jest
```

Then edit **.eslintrc.json**

```
{
   "env":{
     "jest": true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Add environment only for `__tests__` folder

You could add a `.eslintrc.yml` file in your `__tests__` folders, that extends you basic configuration:

```yaml
extends: <relative_path to .eslintrc>
env:
    jest: true
```

If you have only one `__tests__`folder, this solution is the best since it scope jest environment only where it is needed.

### Dealing with many test folders

If you have more test folders (OPs case), I'd still suggest to add those files. And if you have tons of those folders can add them with a simple zsh script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

for folder in **/__tests__/ ;do
    count=$(($(tr -cd '/' <<< $folder | wc -c)))
    echo $folder : $count
    cat <<EOF > $folder.eslintrc.yml
extends: $(printf '../%.0s' {1..$count}).eslintrc
env:
    jest: true
EOF
done
```

This script will look for `__tests__` folders and add a `.eslintrc.yml` file with to configuration shown above. This script has to be launched within the folder containing your parent `.eslintrc`.

Comment: .eslintrc.yml to set second folder to be listed, super nice! To stop indexing it and avoid error messages, you can also set `"ignorePatterns": ["tests/*"]` in eslintrc file

Answer (score 4):

some of the answers *assume* you have `eslint-plugin-jest` installed, however *without* needing to do that, you can simply do **this** in your `.eslintrc` file, **add**:

```
  "globals": {
    "jest": true,
  }
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked - this comment needs more votes.

Answer (score 4):

As of ESLint V 6 (released in late 2019), you can use extends in the glob based config as follows:

```json
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["*.test.js"],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        },
        "plugins": ["jest"],
        "extends": ["plugin:jest/recommended"]
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pattern based configs are scheduled for 2.0.0 release of ESLint. For now, however, you will have to create two separate tasks (as mentioned in the comments). One for tests and one for the rest of the code and run both of them, while providing different .eslintrc files.

P.S. There's a jest environment coming in the next release of ESLint, it will register all of the necessary globals.

Answer (score 2):

I got it running after spending some time trying out different options. Hope this helps anyone else getting stuck.

.eslintrc.json (in root project folder):

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "jest/globals": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard",
        "plugin:jest/all"
    ],
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "jest/no-hooks": [
            "error",
            {
                "allow": [
                    "afterEach",
                    "beforeEach"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "plugins": [
        "jest"
    ]
}
```

Empty .babelrc (in root project folder):

```json
{}
```

.package.json (in root project folder):

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "npx eslint --format=table .",
    "lintfix": "npx eslint --fix ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "aws-sdk-mock": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6"
  }
}
```

VS Code settings.xml (editor configuration: enables auto fix on save + babel parser):

```json
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.lintTask.enable": true,
    "eslint.options": {
        "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ]
```

Answer (score -12):

In your .eslintignore file add the following value:

```
**/__tests__/
```

This should ignore all instances of the __tests__ directory and their children.

Comment: That's not quite what I want, I don't want to ignore the test files, I still want to lint them, I just want to figure out how to specify the necessary options to lint them correctly.

Comment: Very bad idea, eslint helps in all code - including test code.