# Using jest in my react app, describe is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, eslint, eslintrc

I am new to jest and trying to figure out some basic stuff in my following code

```
import * as actions from './IncrementalSearchActions';

describe('Incremental Search Actions', () => {
    it('Should create an incremental search action')
});
```

The questions/confusions I have around this are

1. I get an error saying describe is not defined, how do I import the reuqired module?
2. Is this supposed to be used with Karma/Jasmine?

Comment: How do you run the test? There is no need to import `describe`

Comment: For 2. Jest doesn't need to be used with karma or jasmine, jest itself is something like a all-in-one solution

Comment: How do Import the 'describe' function in ES6, this is my main confusion, do I need to import something in jest?

Comment: No you don't need import anything of jest

Comment: Do you use npm script to run jest?

Comment: if I dont need to import anything where does the describe function come from?

Comment: ok, I found the explanation here https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html, but if I am not importing anything at all how do it add anything to globals?

Comment: Are you getting this error when running the jest command, or from ESLint?

Comment: are the file name `name.test.js`?

Answer (score 249):

I believe the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629389/how-to-use-eslint-with-jest) is the answer to your question.

TL;DR;:

add the following to your `.eslintrc` file:

```
"env": {
    "jest": true
}
```

Comment: You can find all the configuration details for other unit test libraries @ [ESLint Specifying Environments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)

Answer (score -4):

Are your test files under a the "**test**" folder? make sure jest is install properly and listed on your package.json and under scripts have:

```
"test": "jest --coverage",
```

you can run the script with npm test