# Eslint allow extraneous dependencies in tests

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, package.json

In my test files I get eslint error on some imports like

> 'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ["error", { devDependencies:
>   true, }],

this happens only in my second tests directory in some subfolder
in my root tests directory I don't get this errors
I didn't find any settings in package.json or .eslintrc which could cause differentiation.
Currently I have to use

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies*/
```

in my test files which we don't like
If I add

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }]
```

to .eslintrc th rule is off everywhere not just in tests
How can I switch this rule of except of placing .eslintrc to the tests folder? which folders use devDependencies?

Answer (score 24):

You can use an array of globs as follows, which will allow extraneous dependencies to be access from test files where file name matches **/*.test.js

```
"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": ["**/*.test.js"]}]
```

Comment: If using jest, adding `"env": { "jest": true}` to your `eslintrc.json` also works.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611190/using-jest-in-my-react-app-describe-is-not-defined)

Answer (score -3):

You can create a `.eslintignore` file in the project root to disable ESLint for specific files or directories.

And put the following line into it:

```
test/*
```

Reference: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories

---

**Edit:**

If you want to ignore a specific rule for a particular directory, you can put another `.eslintrc` file in that directory.

Reference: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy

Comment: but this would ignore all linting rules in this folder