# describe is not defined when installing jest

Tags: jestjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb, eslintrc

I installed `jest v24.7.1`in my project with:

```
npm install jest -D
```

Then I start writing some test files, However I got these eslint errors:

```
'describe' is not defined. eslint (no-undef)
'it' is not defined. eslint (no-undef)
'expect' is not defined. eslint (no-undef)
```

eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {


env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: ["airbnb", "prettier", "prettier/react"],
  globals: {
    Atomics: "readonly",
    SharedArrayBuffer: "readonly"
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {}
};
```

Should I add another rule or a plugin to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eslint throws \`no-undef\` errors when linting Jest test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398742/eslint-throws-no-undef-errors-when-linting-jest-test-files)

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Add following line in `.eslintrc.js` file

```
"env": {
    "jest": true
}
```

or

```
{
  "plugins": ["jest"]
},
"env": {
  "jest/globals": true
}
```

For more details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629389/how-to-use-eslint-with-jest), it also define the same.

Hope you installed `eslint-plugin-jest` package.If not kindly go through for 
[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jest).

All the configuration details of [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments).

Comment: If you are using VS-code you might need to restart the Es-lint server by pressing ctrl/command + shift + p, then in the command interpreter search for Restart Eslint and click to continue the eslint server.

Comment: Wanted to add that jest also uses some jasmine defines like `fail` so it may be necessary to add `jasmine: true` also

Answer (score 6):

Add following comment line in head of your file

```js
/* globals describe, expect, it */
```

Answer (score 1):

For jest 27 all of this should not be necessary.
Kill `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`.
Then run `npm i`.

Answer (score -7):

Add `/* eslint-disable no-undef */` to the top of your test files.

**sample.test.js**

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

describe("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Comment: This is not correct - you shouldn't just hide the error, adding jest to the environment within eslint fixed this for me.