# eslint throws `no-undef` errors when linting Jest test files

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, eslint

I'm using Jest to write some specs and ESLint to lint the styling.

For my `foo.spec.js` tests, eslint keeps throwing the following errors. It seems to think that `jest`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, etc... are not defined in that file.

```
   11:1   error  'beforeEach' is not defined  no-undef
   12:3   error  'jest' is not defined        no-undef
   14:13  error  'jest' is not defined        no-undef
   18:1   error  'afterEach' is not defined   no-undef
   20:1   error  'describe' is not defined    no-undef
   21:3   error  'it' is not defined          no-undef
   25:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   28:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   31:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   34:3   error  'it' is not defined          no-undef
   38:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   41:5   error  'jest' is not defined        no-undef
   42:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   43:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   46:3   error  'it' is not defined          no-undef
   54:5   error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
   58:5   error  'jest' is not defined        no-undef
```

I believe those are included by jest automatically and so they don't need to be explicitly imported in my spec files. In fact the only thing I import via my `jest.setup.js` file is

```
import "react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each";
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

Is there a way to eliminate these errors without having to disable eslint rules at the top of each individual file or inline?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ESLint with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629389/how-to-use-eslint-with-jest)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Please, add the following to your .eslintrc file:

```
{
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "**/*.spec.js",
        "**/*.spec.jsx"
      ],
      "env": {
        "jest": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 126):

You do not need to add this override option and specify in which files `jest` should be available. Adding only `env` field should be enough.

***.eslintrc.js*:**

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    jest: true
  },
//...
}
```

Comment: This, by itself, doesn't work for me. If I exclude `spec` files in `tsconfig`, I'm able to put together a configuration that fixes the no-def issue, but doesn't lead to consistent linting between jest and production files, which is the Holy Grail I seek. I remain on my quest.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. If someone else needs, my `.eslint.json` file now has: `"env": { "commonjs": true, "es2021": true, "node": true, "jest": true }`

Comment: This is the right answer for next.js in typescript

Comment: Strictly this means that the globals defined by jest will be considered valid in your non test files by the linter. It's unlikely but possible this could lead to something breaking when run in a non test environment that would have been picked up by the linter. That is what the previous answer avoids.

Answer (score 24):

Had a similar problem with eslint throwing no-undef errors for my jest setup.js file with some jest.mocks in it.

Ended up fixing it by using the [ESLint plugin for Jest](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest).

After installing the plugin as a dev dependency, I merged the following into my .eslintrc config file per instructions from the plugin readme.

```
{
  "extends": ["plugin:jest/recommended"],
  "plugins": ["jest"]
}
```

Then the no-undef errors are gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue!.
I saw an answer for adding a comment like this:

```
/* eslint-env jest */
```

This works the best as I dont want to install any unnecessary plugin or config statements.

Add this comment to all your test files and you are done!

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/users/154133/friederbluemle to this user for the simplest solution!

Answer (score 2):

The environment can also be applied to individual files (without modifying configuration files).

For example, use this comment at the top of the file:

```
/* eslint-env jest */
```

This can be useful when there are some files (e.g. `jest.setup.js`), that access `jest.` and are *outside* the regular test folders.

Answer (score 0):

As I am using a StandardJS Linter none of the suggested solution worked for me. Instead, I had to define a global for "it" within my standard-config.

E.g. in `package.json`:

```
...
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "globals": [
      "afterAll",
      "beforeAll",
      "afterEach",
      "jasmine",
      "describe",
      "test",
      "jest",
      "expect",
      "it"
    ]
 }
...
```