# Jest / ESLint fail is not defined

Tags: react-native, jestjs, eslint, babel-jest

I've just generated a fresh project with `npx react-native init` and ESLint is complaining in one of my test files:

```
   9:1   error  'describe' is not defined    no-undef
  12:5   error  'beforeEach' is not defined  no-undef
  16:5   error  'afterEach' is not defined   no-undef
  20:5   error  'test' is not defined        no-undef
  28:17  error  'fail' is not defined        no-undef
  30:13  error  'expect' is not defined      no-undef
```

Based on the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629389/how-to-use-eslint-with-jest), I've added:

```
env: {
    jest: true,
},
```

to my `.eslintrc.js` file. However, ESLint is still complaining with:

```
  28:17  error  'fail' is not defined  no-undef
```

Has anyone already experienced and solved this issue ?

Here are the jest dependencies versions in `package.json`:

```
"babel-jest": "^26.5.2",
"jest": "^26.5.3",
```

Comment: If you're seeing this message in your editor, make sure to turn it off and on again. Sometimes editors don't pick up that the ESLint configuration changed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm seeing it from my Terminal where I execute the command manually.

Comment: Other than that, I'm not really sure. I had the exact same problem as you literally yesterday and I solved it by adding the `env` property in the config. I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56398742/eslint-throws-no-undef-errors-when-linting-jest-test-files) so it's only enabled for the test files (I had to adjust the filter, as well to match my naming scheme of `*.test.ts`) but it did work - ESLint stopped complaining. I also added a small `"rules"` section in the overrides to tweak some stylistic rules for the tests.

Comment: Are you also using `fail` in one of your tests ?

Comment: No, but let me try quickly if it accepts it.

Comment: OK, so I added a very simple test it("fails", function() { fail("always"); })` and the test fails (expectedly). ESLint also complains with a `no-undef` but it doesn't have issues with stuff like `describe` or `expect. I'll have to see what that one doesn't work, it's weird.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so it turns out Jest uses Jasmine's `fail()`.

Updated `.eslintrc.js` by adding Jasmine and it works. No more errors.

```
env: {
    jasmine: true,
    jest: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The former runner, jest-jasmine2, is deprecated in Jest since 27.0.0
and jest-circus is getting used instead.

Update **.eslintrc.js**

```
env: {
    jest: true,
    circus: true,
}
```